# TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, cryptojs

I am generating reset password token using crypto-js version 4.1.1. But I am getting
error when I post my API TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function and everything
is correct in my schema . I am using node version v16.16.0. How to overcome of this issue

```
 // This is my code where I am using rest password 
  import crypto from 'crypto-js';

  userSchema.methods.getResetToken = function () {
      // Generating token
      const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

      //hashing and adding resetPasswordToken to userSchema
      this.resetPasswordToken = crypto
          .createHash("sha256")
          .update(resetToken)
          .digest("hex");

      this.resetPasswordTime = Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000;

      return resetToken;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is my code where I am using rest password 
import crypto from 'crypto-js';
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

userSchema.methods.getResetToken = function() {
  // Generating token
  // use uuid or nanoid 
  const resetToken = nanoid(64)

  // hashing and adding resetPasswordToken to userSchema
  this.resetPasswordToken = crypto.SHA256(resetToken).toString(crypto.enc.Hex);

  this.resetPasswordTime = Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000;

  return resetToken;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  crypto-js has a completely different but well documented interface 
  compared to node.js crypto library

  // docs crypto-js
  https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/

  // nodejs crypto library docs
  https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html


  I found this problem solution from here:

  https://peaku.co/questions/54762-el-cartero-genera-hash-criptografico- 
  da-error:-typeerror:-cryptocreatehash-no-es-una-funcion
```